# RabbitMQ - Send message in chunks

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'm working with Spring and RabbitMQ and having a case in which I would like to send a message of 20 MB +- but without loading the whole 20 MB to the RAM.

Is there an option to send message to RabbitMQ in chunks/parts?

I didn't find a way to send the message in chunks

Comment: Is setting transfer-encoding : chunked to request header is an option while you are sending a message to RabbitMQ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it's really up to your library. I checked the [Javadocs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.6.5/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#basicPublish(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.rabbitmq.client.AMQP.BasicProperties,%20byte[])), and unfortunately `basicPublish()` only accepts `byte[]` as input, not a stream.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I'm not sure if transfer-encoding will do the job...
My goal is to not load all the byte[] payload to the memory.. and I didn't find a way to do it.